# Passing Parameters To PHP Table Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, hyperlink

I want the second and third columns of my php table to be a hyperlink to a different page for each row.  I need to pass 3 parameters to the hyperlink
1) The value from the first column - `empID` listed in the table below

2) The value from $weekStart - selected from a `input type="date"` at top of page

3) The value from $weekEnd - selected from a `input type="date"` at top of page

I am trying this syntax, but it is not passing in the parameters and I am getting a page not found error.  How should this syntax be altered so that it passes all 3 params and navigates to the appropriate page?

```
Week Start:<input type="date" name="weekStart">
Week End:<input type="date" name="weekEnd">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Employee Data">

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $weekStart = $_POST['weekStart'];
    $weekEnd = $_POST['weekEnd'];

    //Generate Table Here
}
?>
foreach ($tsql as $res) 
{
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>" . $res->EmpID . "</td>";
    print "<td><a href="DailySales.php?param1=$weekStart;param2=$weekEnd'.$Row['EmpID'].'">'.$Row['DailySales'].'</a>'" . $res->DailySales . "</td>";
    print "<td><a href="WeeklySales.php?param1=$weekStart;param2=$weekEnd'.$Row['EmpID'].'">'.$Row['SalesForWeek'].'</a>'" . $res->SalesForWeek . "</td>";
    print "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting those 3 parameter values from? Not really enough information here to answer the question to be honest.

Comment: The value from the first column is EmpID in the table, the values $weekStart and $weekEnd are captured from two input type="date" at the top of the page.  Does that help clarify my ambiguity?

Comment: Yeah it helps, can you post that bit of the HTML too please, and update your question with that info :)

Comment: Is this being done on a button click? Trying to figure out the order of operations here, because those links will be wrong on page load. You're populating them before the input is entered it seems?

Comment: @RickCalder - yes the table is being populated on button click.  When button is pressed I store the values in php variables and run a sql query.  I think I have added enough information for help in my question now.  Thank you for working with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't append the string well. Please try the below code

```
foreach ($tsql as $res) 
{
   print "<tr>";
   print "<td>" . $res->EmpID . "</td>";
   print "<td><a href='DailySales.php?param1=".$weekStart."&param2=".$weekEnd."&param3=".$Row['EmpID']."'>".$Row['DailySales']."</a>" . $res->DailySales . "</td>";
   print "<td><a href='WeeklySales.php?param1=".$weekStart."&param2=".$weekEnd."&param3=".$Row['EmpID']."'>".$Row['SalesForWeek']."</a>" . $res->SalesForWeek . "</td>";
   print "</tr>";
}
```

If it still shows not found page, then please check the file names.

Update: I hope you need to replace some variables in your loop as updated in the below code

```
foreach ($tsql as $res) 
{
   print "<tr>";
   print "<td>" . $res->EmpID . "</td>";
   print "<td><a href='DailySales.php?param1=".$weekStart."&param2=".$weekEnd."&param3=".$res->EmpID."'>".$res->DailySales."</a></td>";
   print "<td><a href='WeeklySales.php?param1=".$weekStart."&param2=".$weekEnd."&param3=".$res->EmpID."'>".$res->SalesForWeek."</a></td>";
   print "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: This will add the hyperlink and redirect as needed, but for some reason the data gets skewed when I add the hyperlink column.  For example, randomly in the table it will add a blank row and push everything to the right 1 on random employeeID's?

Comment: Sorry @Bell, I do not understand your question. Is there no validation to not insert empty records?

Comment: there is no blank results if you run the query in SSMS.  The table set-up displays as it should w/ no hyperlinks.  For some peculiar reason, when I add in the hyperlink syntax the grid results will sometimes add in a  ghost column and certain employeeID will have 4 rows instead of 3

Comment: Could it be that I had to shorten your syntax to print "<td><a print "<td><a href='DailySales.php?param1=".$weekStart."&param2=".$weekEnd."&param3=".$res->EmpID."</a>" . $res->DailySales . "</td>"; --- as f I did not it would duplicate the DailySales value (show them side by side, instead of 4 it would show 44)

Comment: I think that I got your question now. I thought you are referring DB table :). Normally the type of issue that you mentioned happens when tags are not closed properly. As far as the code we see in this post, the tags are properly closed. Might need to look into other parts of code. Can you please post another question with more code around this code block as these are 2 different issues?

Comment: Oh, I just read your last comment. I will update the answer to your needs. Please check the 2nd code block in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested and I'm not 100% sure what the data in those links were supposed to be doing, but I think this should give you a solid starting point and you can tweak the HTML generation to get what you want.

I wouldn't bother trying to do it in PHP at all, pass the entire data set to JS and do it there.

```
Week Start:<input type="date" name="weekStart" id="weekStart">
Week End:<input type="date" name="weekEnd" id="weekEnd">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Employee Data">

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $weekStart = $_POST['weekStart'];
    $weekEnd = $_POST['weekEnd'];

    //Generate Table Here
}

// Create a JSON version of your data to pass to the script
$data = json_encode( $tsql );
?>

<!-- Create an empty table for your data-->
<table id="employee-table"></table>

<script> 
$("#submitForm").on("click", function(e) {
  // Stop the form from reloading the page
  e.preventDefault();

  // Set up your variables, you'll need to add ID's to the form inputs
  var employees = <?php echo $data; ?>;
  // See the employees data in your inspector console
  console.log(employees);

  var weekStart = $("#weekStart").val();
  var weekEnd = $("#weekEnd").val();

  // Generate the HTML for all the employees
  var html = "";
  for( var1=0; i<employees.length; i++ ) {
    html += "<tr>";
    html += "<td>" . employees[i].EmpID . "</td>";
    html += "<td><a href='DailySales.php?param1='" + weekStart + "'&param2='" + weekEnd + "'&param3='" + employees[i].id +">"  + employees[i].DailySales + "</a></td>";
    html += "<td><a href='WeeklySales.php?param1='" + weekStart + "'&param2='" + weekEnd + "'&param3='" + employees[i].id +"'>" + employees[i].SalesForWeek + "</a></td>";
    html += "</tr>";
  }

  // Insert the HTML that you generated into the table.
  $("#employee-table").html(html);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is your var html generating the same thing as the php <table> above?  (Haven't tested yet just trying to get a feel for it)

Comment: Pretty close I think, I'm not really clear on what that HTML in your original should have been generating because I'm not familiar with the data. But it should be relatively obvious how to tweak it if it isn't exactly right :) console.log() is your friend here.